# Creating an empty deque in Python with a max length?

Tags: python, deque, maxlength

I'm looking at the documentation for a Python deque, and it looks like the constructor is `deque([iterable[, maxlen]])`. Is there no way to make an empty deque (that is, without specifying the iterable) with a max length?

Comment: The iterable can be an empty list or tuple.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could provide a list literal directly, so you don't have to declare anything on a separate line:

```
>>> collections.deque([], 42)
deque([], maxlen=42)
```

You could also provide `maxlen` as a named argument:

```
>>> collections.deque(maxlen=23)
deque([], maxlen=23)
```